# How to get rows having sum equal to given value

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is table contain

```
ID     Qty
----------
1       2
2       4
3       1
4       5
```

Now if i had to choose rows where sum of Qty equals to 10,
How can i do this ?

like 2+4+1 = 7
but if i add 5 then 12

so ignore 2, then
4+1+5 = 10

How can i achieve this ?

Edit:

I want any possible combination which sums up to gives value.
suppose 7 then any rows which sums up to 7
like wise if 8 then any rows sums up to 8

want row/rows having combination equals to given value.

Comment: How many numbers do you want to add up? Always 3?

Comment: Will there only ever be one solution? If there is more than one possible solution do you want all options or just the first you come across?

Comment: Can you explain what you need this for? Maybe there is another way to achieve what you need then you are describing

Comment: Getting SQL Server to solve [NP-complete problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) in a reasonable amount of time is unlikely to occur.

Answer (score 6):

The problem you want to solve is called the [subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum) problem. Unfortunately, it is [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

This means that, whether you use SQL or any other language to solve it, you will only be able to solve very small instances of the problem, i.e. ones with only a few entries in the table. Otherwise, the runtime will become excessive, since it grows exponentially with the number of rows in the table. The reason for this is that there is essentially no better way of finding the solution than to try all possible combinations.

If an approximate solution is acceptable, there is a polynomial time algorithm, which is described on the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to be exactly always three numbers that add to 10, then this

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  MyTable t1
  JOIN
  MyTable t2 ON t1.ID <> t2.ID 
  JOIN
  MyTable t3 ON t1.ID <> t3.ID AND t2.ID <> t3.ID
WHERE
  t1.Qty + t2.Qty + t3.Qty = 10
```

If you want 2 or 4 or 5 numbers then you can't really do it in SQL

Edit:

- Updated to ignore by ID not Qty
- And again: **If you want 2 or 4 or 5 numbers then you can't really do it in SQL**

Comment: not always 3 number, their can be any comination, i want the rows whose sum comes equal to number user passed

Comment: You could write a stored procedure that dynamically writes the stored procedure above for (n) entries to add up then executes it. Start at 1 entry, check if any rows get returned. If no rows, then dynamically generate SQL for 2 entries. Iterate up to the number of rows in the table. Not sure what you will do if there are more than one solution for (n) items to sum

Comment: @Humdum: unless you specify a upper limit, then it really isn't practical in SQL

Comment: @balexandre: I can't access pastebin in work, so I'll try tonight with a damn sight more rows...

Answer (score 2):

When you are dealing with such task in SQL you need to go to the cursors approach.

Cursors let you perform row by row operations and that's what you need, for example:

- You want to make groups of where the summed quantity is 10

This are the tasks

- select all the table into a temp table `#TBL_ALL`
- loop row by row and when the rows sum up 10, delete from the temp table and insert into a final temp table `#TBL_FINAL`
- do this until the `#TBL_ALL` sum cant be performed

An example:

**Test table:**

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblExample]    Script Date: 06/09/2011 11:25:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblExample](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblExample] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Test Data:**

```
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 2;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 4;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 5;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 5;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 11;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 2;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 3;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 4;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 7;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 9;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO tblExample SELECT 2;
```

**Store procedure:**

> http://pastebin.com/EFeZcKXf

Results:

**Grouped table:**

```
ids qty group
12  9   1
7   1   1
11  7   2
9   3   2
4   5   3
5   5   3
2   4   4
10  4   4
14  2   4
```

**Numbers not used:**

```
id  qty 
1   2
8   2
3   1
13  1
6   11
```

Hope it helps

---

SP for those who cant access PasteBin

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getGroups
(
    @groupByQty int, -- grouping number
    @numberRuns int  -- how many loops

    -- usage: getGroups 10, 10
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- declare all variables
DECLARE  @rowId      int,
         @rowQty     int,
         @rowTotal   int,
         @groupId    int,
         @totalRuns  int,
         @continue   bit

-- set up our final temporary table
CREATE TABLE #TBL_COUNT
(
  ids NVARCHAR(4000),
  qty int,
  [group] int
)

-- initializate variable
SET @groupId = 1;
SET @continue = 1;
SET @totalRuns = 0;
SELECT Id, Qty INTO #TBL_ALL FROM tblExample ORDER BY Qty DESC;

WHILE @totalRuns <= @numberRuns 
BEGIN
    -- declare the cursor
    DECLARE Product CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, Qty FROM #TBL_ALL ORDER BY Qty DESC;

    OPEN Product;
    FETCH Product INTO @rowId, @rowQty;

    PRINT ' ';
    PRINT '### Run: ' + CAST(@totalRuns AS nvarchar(10)) + ' #################################################################';
    PRINT 'Grouping Table by ' + CAST(@groupByQty AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | group id = ' + CAST(@groupId AS nvarchar(10));

    -- Retrieve and process the first row

    SELECT Top 1 @rowId = Id, @rowQty = Qty FROM #TBL_ALL ORDER BY Qty DESC;
    PRINT 'First Row: id = ' + CAST(@rowId AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | qty = ' + CAST(@rowQty AS nvarchar(10));

    -- sum it up and see if we have @groupByQty
    SELECT @rowTotal = ISNULL(SUM(qty),0) FROM #TBL_COUNT WHERE [group] = @groupId;
    PRINT 'Current sum in #TBL_COUNT: @groupId = '+ CAST(@groupId AS nvarchar(10)) +' | @rowTotal = ' + CAST(@rowTotal AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | (@rowTotal + @rowQty) = ' + CAST((@rowTotal + @rowQty) AS nvarchar(10));

    IF @rowQty > @groupByQty
    BEGIN
        PRINT '  x First row has an unused number';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      -- handle result
      IF (@rowTotal + @rowQty) = @groupByQty
      BEGIN

        PRINT '+++ Current sum is ' + CAST(@groupByQty AS nvarchar(10)) + ' +++';

        -- save number
        INSERT INTO #TBL_COUNT SELECT @rowId, @rowQty, @groupId;
        PRINT '### Inserted final # into #TBL_COUNT : id = ' + CAST(@rowId AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | qty = ' + CAST(@rowQty AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | group = ' + CAST(@groupId AS nvarchar(10));

        -- remove from table as we use it already
        DELETE FROM #TBL_ALL WHERE Id = @rowId;

        -- we got 10, let's change our Groupping
        SET @groupId = (@groupId + 1);

        PRINT 'New group id: ' + CAST(@groupId AS nvarchar(10));

      END
      ELSE 
      BEGIN   
        IF (@rowTotal + @rowQty) < @groupByQty
        BEGIN
            PRINT '### Inserted into #TBL_COUNT : id = ' + CAST(@rowId AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | qty = ' + CAST(@rowQty AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | group = ' + CAST(@groupId AS nvarchar(10));

            -- save number 
            INSERT INTO #TBL_COUNT SELECT @rowId, @rowQty, @groupId;

            -- remove from table as we use it already
            DELETE FROM #TBL_ALL WHERE Id = @rowId;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            PRINT '  x Unmatch number, will handle this latter';
        END
      END
    END 

    -- start the main processing loop
    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
       BEGIN

          FETCH Product INTO @rowId, @rowQty;
          PRINT '@@Fetch_Status = ' + CAST(@@Fetch_Status AS nvarchar(100));

          IF @@Fetch_Status < 0
          BEGIN
            BREAK
          END

          -- we have the values of our row, let's use them
          PRINT 'Fetched Row: id = ' + CAST(@rowId AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | qty = ' + CAST(@rowQty AS nvarchar(10));

          -- sum it up and see if we have @groupByQty
          SELECT @rowTotal = ISNULL(SUM(qty),0) FROM #TBL_COUNT WHERE [group] = @groupId;
          PRINT 'Current sum in #TBL_COUNT: @groupId = '+ CAST(@groupId AS nvarchar(10)) +' | @rowTotal = ' + CAST(@rowTotal AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | (@rowTotal + @rowQty) = ' + CAST((@rowTotal + @rowQty) AS nvarchar(10));

          -- handle result
          IF (@rowTotal + @rowQty) = @groupByQty
          BEGIN

            PRINT '+++ Current sum is ' + CAST(@groupByQty AS nvarchar(10)) + ' +++';

            -- save number
            INSERT INTO #TBL_COUNT SELECT @rowId, @rowQty, @groupId;
            PRINT '### Inserted final # into #TBL_COUNT : id = ' + CAST(@rowId AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | qty = ' + CAST(@rowQty AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | group = ' + CAST(@groupId AS nvarchar(10));

            -- remove from table as we use it already
            DELETE FROM #TBL_ALL WHERE Id = @rowId;

            -- we got 10, let's change our Groupping
            SET @groupId = (@groupId + 1);

            PRINT 'New group id: ' + CAST(@groupId AS nvarchar(10));

            -- start again
            BREAK; 

          END
          ELSE 
          BEGIN   
            IF (@rowTotal + @rowQty) < @groupByQty
            BEGIN
                PRINT '### Inserted into #TBL_COUNT : id = ' + CAST(@rowId AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | qty = ' + CAST(@rowQty AS nvarchar(10)) + ' | group = ' + CAST(@groupId AS nvarchar(10));

                -- save number 
                INSERT INTO #TBL_COUNT SELECT @rowId, @rowQty, @groupId;

                -- remove from table as we use it already
                DELETE FROM #TBL_ALL WHERE Id = @rowId;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                PRINT '  x Unmatch number, will handle this latter';
            END
          END

       END -- END WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0

       SET @totalRuns = @totalRuns + 1;

       -- Close and dealocate
       CLOSE Product;
       DEALLOCATE Product;

   END -- END WHILE totalRuns <= @numberRuns

   -- let's sum our last group and remove it if it's not @groupByQty
   SELECT @rowTotal = ISNULL(SUM(qty),0) FROM #TBL_COUNT WHERE [group] = @groupId;
   IF @rowTotal <> @groupByQty
   BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TBL_ALL ON
    INSERT INTO #TBL_ALL (Id, Qty) SELECT Ids, Qty FROM #TBL_COUNT WHERE [group] = @groupId;
    DELETE FROM #TBL_COUNT WHERE [group] = @groupId;
   END

SET NOCOUNT OFF;

-- Show and Delete temp tables
SELECT * FROM #TBL_COUNT;
SELECT * FROM #TBL_ALL;
DROP TABLE #TBL_COUNT;
DROP TABLE #TBL_ALL;
```

**P.S.** I'm not a SQL Professional, so bear with me if I did something weird, and keep in mind that this is a performance waste, maybe someone can use the the Loop without Cursors, [more in this page](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/operations-no-cursors/3/)

Comment: I don't understand the code entirely, but I'm sort of sceptical that it'll work in the general case because it appears to use a greedy strategy that may mislead it into making the wrong decisions (and also because it seems to be a polynomial time algorithm, and subset sum is NP-complete). For example, does it handle the following sequence of numbers correctly (with a desired sum of 10): 2, 7, 5, 3?

Comment: try your self, open a db, create a table, insert the data and run the SP, it's not 100% as I didn't spend to much time on it, but it's doable. For your example: yes, as it orders the data by `qty`, so the number will be 7, 5, 3, 2: **processing:** keep 7; 7+5 > 10 = discharge 5; 7+3 = 10 -> copy to temp; 0+2 < 10 -> keep 2; loop; 2+5 < 10 -> keep 5; end; remove last group if sum is <> 10;

Comment: I missed the bit about the sorting... but I still think the "greediness" can have unwanted effects. As another example, how about this sequence (again with a desired sum of 10): 5, 4, 4, 2? As I understand the algorithm, it will pick and keep 5 and 4 (since their combined sum is still less than 10) and then reject the other 4 and the 2, since they will both cause the sum to overflow...

Comment: You right, as it is now it wont do, but I can easily change the flow to discharge the `5` and continue with the 2nd number, and so forth. I do think that it's an easy task. Then again, I'm not an SQL Pro.

Answer (score -1):

If u add always 3 numbers its like gbn said, if not then u have to check every combination of ur rows which gives u 2 to the number_of_rows power cobinations and i dont see how can it be done on sql in one query. If u use loop in sql sure its possible but u should find some good algorithm to finish this task.