# Row_number() select only rows of sum X

Tags: mysql

```
ID | PRICE 
1 | 40 
2 | 50 
3 | 100 
4 | 10
```

Select only those id's that sum of price will be 130 for example

IDS : 1,2,4 { sum :: 100 } skip the rest

if applied ordering price desc, it would get ID 3,4

I tried something like this but won't work

```
set @rownum= 0;
set @rownum2 = 0;
select @rownum := @rownum + 1 as r, id_wydatku
FROM wydatki
where sum (
    select wydatki.kwota_brutto
    from wydatki
    where  @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1<= r
) < 1000
```

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4713/41

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: 40 + 50 + 10 = 100

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of this problem is NP-Complete, as stated on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289662/2768318

Having said that, if you want to try to solve this (in case you have few rows) you should adapt this solution to your problem : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b720/39